# Transforming dataframe rows in Scala with a lot of columns

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I would like to change the value of multiple fields in a row of a dataframe `df`. Normally, I would do a row to row transformation using a map. Something like:

```
+---+---------+
|num|name     |
+---+---------+
|  1|Hydrogen |
|  2|Helium   |
+---+---------+
df.map(row=>{
      val name = row.getAs("name").toString.toUpperCase
      (row(0),name)
    })
```

But now I have a dataframe which has a very elaborate schema of many columns, out of which I would want to change the value of only some columns. The change in the value of one column is dependent on other columns. How can I avoid writing all the column values (like `row.get(0), row.get(1) ... row.get(30)`) in the tuple but only write the ones which have changed? Consider a `df` with this schema:

```
case class DFSchema(id: String, name: String, map1: Map[String, String], ... , map30[Sting, String])
```

I want to update the keys and values of `df.select("map30")` and modify `"name"` only if `id` is `"city"`. Of course, there are more such transformations to be made in other columns (represented in schema as `mapX`.

I did not consider using UDF for this problem as even if the UDF returns a struct of many columns, I do not know how to change multiple columns using `withColumn()` as it only accepts "one" column name. However, solutions using UDF are equally welcome as using `.map` over rows.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output based on your input? i understand the complexity part, but don't visualize the challenge...

Comment: would a combination of withColumn and when function not work for your case?

Comment: @jpg, I have added a schema and sample problem. @urug I don't understand how using `when` would help to modify multiple columns. Could you be more explicit. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```scala
val rules = Seq(
  "columnA" -> lit(20),
  "columnB" -> col("columnB").plus(col("columnC")),
  "columnC" -> col("columnC").minus(col("columnD")),
  "columnN" -> col("columnA").plus(col("columnB")).plus(col("columnC"))
)

def (inputDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  rules.foldLeft(inputDf) {
    case (df, (columnName, ruleColumn)) => df.withColumn(columnName, ruleColumn)
  }
}
```

Here we have `rules` which is a sequence of pairs where the first value is a name of the target column we want to change/add and the second one is a rule which should be applied using dependent columns.

Using the `foldLeft` operation we apply all the rules to the input `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
   df.show(false)

    val newColumns = df.columns.map { x =>
      if (x == "name") {
        when(col("id") === "city", lit("miami")).otherwise(col("name")).as("name")
      } else if (x == "map30") {
        when(col("id") === "city", map(lit("h"), lit("update"), lit("n"), lit("new"))).otherwise(col("map30")).as("map30")
      } else {
        col(x).as(x)
      }
    }

    val cleanDf = df.select(newColumns: _*)

    cleanDf.show(false)
```

Comment: Hi there! This may solve the OP's problem, but it would be an even better answer if it explained *why* it solves the OP's problem. What does your answer do that the OP didn't think of, and why is it the right thing?

Comment: This solves the problem ,because select all atributes of your dataframe and when select for example the column 'name' , I verify with the when method thad this column contain city and if this meets the conditicion aply update otherwise return the same column without transformation